# How to covert the data of array of objects type string to int in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
for (i=0;i<y;i++)
{
stringstream ss(student[i].getstudent());
int MARK;
ss>>MARK;

cout<<student[i].getstudent()/2<<endl;
}
```

Is this a proper way to convert the data type in the array of objects into `int`? I've tried this many times but it hasn't worked.

Comment: What does `student[i].getstudent()` return?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp mark,i need to convert the mark of the students which is string type to int.

Comment: The last line should be `cout << MARK/2 << endl;`

Comment: It still cannot work.Although the string is successfully convert to int, but the output is incorrect

Comment: What do mean "incorrect". Maybe you want a `float` output.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, pre-C++11 you'd use a `stringstream` to convert from an `std::string` to an `int` or `atoi()`.

If you however have access to C++11 I'd recommend using `std::stoi()`.